# Method : how can I detect that data is not in file

Tags: c#, mongodb

I develop in C# on a mongoDb database.

I receive each day some xml files representing some cars.

I insert this cars in my mongodb Database.

Tomorrow, I will receive some xml files but maybe a car that I insert today will not be in the file tomorrow.

How can I detect that a car available in my file yesterday ( and insert in my database ) is not in my file today .

For example, in my mongoDb database :

XML File of 2020-11-16 :

```
Car toyota 11
Car Ford 19
Car Tesla 78
```

XML File of 2020-11-17

```
Car toyota 11
Car Tesla 78
Car BMW 89
```

I want to mark `car Ford 19` as old because he's not present in the file anymore ( so can be deleted ) and `Car BMW 89` as new because he was not present yeterday ( so can be treated ).

How Can I do That ?

Answer (score 0):

First, `UPDATE` all as old.

Second, `UPDATE` as normal if exists, or not `INSERT` as new.

[This](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is using Upsert() function.
Upsert will

1. Insert a new document if a document with that _id does not exist in a collection.
2. Update document if a document with that _id does exist in the collection.